# Dialog boxes not opening second time. GTK+, Glade and C

Tags: c, windows, gtk, glade

I am designing an interface using GTK+ and Glade. I have created a few dialog boxes using glade and have connected through a C code. They work perfectly fine for the first time but when the user tries to reuse it the program stops working.
The command window is giving

```
(program_name.exe:1668): GLib-GObject-Warning **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(program_name.exe:1688): GLib-Gobject-Critical **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
(program)name.exe:1668): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET(widget)' failed
```

Here is the code

```
GtkWidget *entry_obs_cells[12];
void
on_observation_cells_activate(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data){
GtkWidget *observation_cells;
observation_cells = glade_xml_get_widget (gxml, "dialog3_obs_cells");
GtkWidget *label1, *label2, *label3, *label4, *label5, *label6, *label7, *label8, *label9, *label10, *time_interval;
label1 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label1");
label2 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label2_obs_cells");
label3 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label3_obs_cells");
label4 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label4_obs_cells");
label5 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label5_obs_cells");
label6 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label6_obs_cells");
label7 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label7_obs_cells");
label8 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label8_obs_cells");
label9 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label9_obs_cells");
label10 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "label10_obs_cells");


GtkWidget *button1,*button2;
button1 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml,"Save_obs_cells");
button2 = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml,"Cancel_obs_cells");

entry_obs_cells[1] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry1_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[2] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry2_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[3] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry3_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[4] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry4_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[5] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry5_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[6] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry6_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[7] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry7_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[8] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry8_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[9] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry9_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[10] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry10_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[11] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry_obs_cells");
entry_obs_cells[12] = glade_xml_get_widget(gxml, "entry12_obs_cells");

gtk_widget_show (observation_cells);
g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON(button1), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_Save_obs_cells_activate), observation_cells);
g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON(button2), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_Cancel_obs_cells_activate), NULL);
```

}

```
on_Save_obs_cells_activate()
{
    char *record_results=(char*)malloc(500);
    strcpy(record_results,project_dir);
    strcat(record_results,"\\Record_results.txt");
    printf("\n%s\n",record_results);
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(record_results, "w+");
    fprintf(file, "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[11])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[11])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[1])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[2])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[3])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[4])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[5])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[6])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[7])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[8])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[9])),gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_obs_cells[10])));
    fclose(file);

}

void
on_Cancel_obs_cells_activate (GtkButton *button, gpointer dialog)
{
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
}
```

Comment: You sure you setted your display correctly?
However as i remember the critical error was encountered like a gtk bug in Ubuntu.

Comment: replace `gtk_widget_destroy()` with `gtk_widget_hide()` if you want to reuse the widgets (otherwise they get deallocated).

Comment: @Edenia: setting display part I did not understand. I am working using windows.

Comment: @mfro: the issues is also there when I am using the default close button (top right corner) instead of the Cancel button in the dialog box.

Comment: As mfro said above you need to call `gtk_widget_hide()` instead of `gtk_widget_destroy()` also you will need to connect the `destroy` signal to `gtk_widget_hide_on_delete()` to stop the window being destroyed when you click on the close button in the top right corner. Glade XML is deprecated, it has been replaced by [GtkBuilder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkBuilder.html) which is included with Gtk itself.

Comment: Sorry that should have been connect `delete-event` to `gtk_widget_hide_on_delete()` not `destroy`

Comment: @PhillipWood Really late to change everything to GtkBuilder now. The other suggestion seems appropriate to me. WIll try and update.

Comment: GtkBuilder was added 7 years ago and libglade was deprecated over five years ago -- so yeah it is indeed quite late :) @PhillipWood please write that comment as an answer so this question doesn't seem unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mfro said above you need to call `gtk_widget_hide()` instead of `gtk_widget_destroy()` also you will need to connect the `delete-event` signal to `gtk_widget_hide_on_delete()` to stop the window being destroyed when you click on the close button in the top right corner.

Glade XML is deprecated, it has been replaced by [GtkBuilder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkBuilder.html) which is included with Gtk itself. It should be quite easy to use search and replace to change the glade_xml function calls to the corresponding GtkBuilder ones. If you created the xml interface descriptions in glade they will work with GtkBuilder without any problem.